# Login de autorização

Tags: c#

Galera eu tenho login de autorização de acesso, só que quando executo a autorização ele apagar o anterior e fica o atual. Por ex: Eu tenho o login usuário (básico), para executar uma ação o usuário precisa ser liberado por um login (Administrador). Estou fazendo esse código abaixo. Mas quando executo ele , ele fica logado como Login (Administrado) e não mais como login (básico).

```
if (LoginUsuárioCache.Cargo == FuncionárioCargo.Administrador)
{
    ConexaoLeituraBanco conexaoLeituraBanco = new ConexaoLeituraBanco();
    using (var connection = conexaoLeituraBanco.GetConnection())
    {
       connection.Open();
       using (MySqlCommand commad = new MySqlCommand())
       {                                    
            commad.Connection = connection; 
            commad.CommandText = "UPDATE pdv_historico SET sangria = sangria"; 
            commad.Parameters.AddWithValue("sangria", sangria);
            commad.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            MySqlDataReader reader = commad.ExecuteReader();
            connection.Close();
            this.Close();
       }                                                               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu UPDATE não tem WHERE. Com isso, afeta todos os registros da tabela.

```
"UPDATE pdv_historico SET sangria = sangria"
```

Você deve verificar de acordo com a sua lógica, e passar o ID (ou outro campo) apropriado como cláusula. Exemplificando de maneira bem básica:

```
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@IdUsuario";
param.Value         = usuario.Id;

"UPDATE pdv_historico SET sangria = sangria WHERE IDUsuario=@IdUsuario"
```

Comment: A parte de update está correta. Eu já coloquei o WHERE. Ele faz o UPDATE corretamente dos valores. O problema é que ele volta logado como Administrador  e não como estava antes. Como login (básico).

Comment: Como está o resto do seu código?

Comment: UPDATE pdv_historico SET sangria = @ sangria WHERE usuario = '" + txtNome.Text + "' ORDER BY idpdv_historico DESC LIMIT 1"; Depois ele faz a alteração no mysql onde o nome do usuario basico for igual ao (txtNome.text). Depois fecha a conexão, fecha a tele de login e volta ao FORM inicial.